# Theorem of Yan implies Nikisin-Yan?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a paper by Jia-An Yan (1980) it says that Theorem 2 should imply Theorem 1.

Theorem 2 states: Let $K\subset \mathbb{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be convex and $0\in K$. Then the following are equivalent:

i) $\forall \eta\in\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^1,~\eta\neq 0 ~\exists c>0$ s.t. $c\eta\notin \overline{K-\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^{\infty}}^{\mathbb{L}^1}$

ii) $\forall A\in \mathcal{F},~\mathbb{P}[A]>0~\exists c>0$ s.t. $c1_A\notin \overline{K-\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^{\infty}}^{\mathbb{L}^1}$

iii) $\exists Z\in\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^{\infty},~Z>0~\mathbb{P}-$a.s. s.t. $\sup\limits_{\zeta\in K}\mathbb{E}[\zeta Z]<\infty$.

Theorem 1 states: Let $K\subset \mathbb{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be convex. Suppose 
$\forall \epsilon >0~\exists c>0$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}[\zeta>c]<\epsilon~\forall \zeta\in K$. Then, there exists $ Z\in\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^{\infty},~Z>0~\mathbb{P}-$a.s. s.t. $\sup\limits_{\zeta\in K}\mathbb{E}[\zeta Z]<\infty.$

Theorem 2 should imply Theorem 1 in the sense that the assumptions of Theorem 1 should imply the assumption ii) of Theorem 2. Although it says one should choose $\epsilon=\mathbb{P}[A]/2$ and then consider $2c1_A$ but embarrassingly enough I still struggle to show this.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Link to the paper: http://archive.numdam.org/article/SPS_1980__14__220_0.pdf

Comment: Thanks for linking to the paper and writing out!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\eta \in K$ be arbitrary. So, as the paper notes, we have that, for all $\eta$, $P(\eta > c) < \frac{P(A)}{2}$. Now, consider the random variable $X = 2c1_A$, and the set $S = \{ w \in \Omega: X(w) > \eta(w) \}$. We know that $P(S) \geq P(A) - P(\eta > c)>0$ by union bound, since the union of the sets $S$ and $\{\eta > c\}$ contain all $w \in A$. (If $w \in A$, either $\eta(w) \leq c$, in which case $X > \eta$, or ...)

So, there is positive probability that $X > \eta$ for any $\eta$ in $K$. However, that means that it cannot be written as a combination of some $\eta$ in $K$ minus a non-negative function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Are there no problems in this argument when taking the $\mathbb{L}^1$ closure?
By what you have shown I would say it follows that $X\notin K-\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}^{\infty}$ but not for the closure.
Am I wrong here?

Comment: Eh, all the inequalities are strict, and you are giving yourself a huge room with that factor 2 (most of this argument can be carried with like $1 + \delta$ instead of a $2$, so it is probably ok. (In particular, you can show that $X > (1+ \delta) \eta_n$ for all $\eta_n \in K$, so even if you were to take limits, I am pretty sure you will not be able to set it equal since $X$ is strictly positive in some place, and there will be a uniform gap in a compact interval there; feel free to try it out though!)

Comment: I'm sorry, you are totally right. It is just playing around a bit with the factor. Thank you again!